# accessing .so - extension context does not have a method

Tags: unix, air, root, swc

I have been playing around with a spare playbook to see what features i can unearth/unlock by rooting.

I have found a directory containg .so files which i am aware we can access by creating a mobile library > swc > ane in flash builder.

I have done all this and i am able to create and load an extension which contains a libbluetooth.so.1 file which hopefully will give me bluetooth access.

I am at an 3500 error which has lasted me a lot longer hence the request for support. Extension context does not have a method is what error is given and it is because I don't know what method to try in this line of code now that i have packaged and accessed the .so file succesfully. Any help or suggestions appreciated.

```
var result:Object = ctx.call("bt_connect");
```

Comment: If you want just a list of functions in that shared library then try the `nm` tool.

Comment: i am accessing the unix file system (playbook) using winSCP which I don't think gives me access to nm tool- or does it?

Comment: If you have `scp` you probably can just `ssh` into the thing, right?

Comment: yes, but i have only 1 week experience of wnscp, ssh and unix so please can you explain a little if there is a chance to find out whats in this .so?

Comment: `ssh user@address` to login into the box, substitute `user` with your user name, and `address` with name or address of the machine. You'll get a command line like `user@address$ `. `cd` to the directory where the `.so` file is. Then do `nm libbluetooth.so.1`. This will give you a long list of symbols, so you might pipe it into `less` like `nm libbluetooth.so.1 | less` to page through it.

Comment: Here's description of what `nm` does: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nm/

Comment: thanks Nikolai, I did see something about NM this morning when searching how to extract info out of .so files but i found that it was for unix os, my setup is windows xp machine connected to playbok via ssh using usb, when i type nm libbluetooth.so is doesn't recognize nm ??

Comment: my playbook runs unix (i think)

Comment: See if you have `objdump`, use the `--sym` flag. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump

Comment: no, i have no access to --sym, objdump or nm in ssh. Is extracting info exclusively for users who have unix os on thir pc? No online tool to get this done?

Comment: I have no idea what your target platform is. It's probably some Linux/Android. To figure that out you can try `uname -a` on the `ssh` prompt. Then search the internet for what's available there.

Comment: I managed to find elf-reader program in playbook ndk files, i am now extracting info! Thank you for your help